# How can I add the new DataFrame into Excel as a new column without it overlapping to my results in the first column?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe

I am trying to gather some results into an Excel file, but I don't know how to add things up to Excel without losing the results I already heave into my first column.
Here is my code.

```
Fs = [f"F{i:02d}" for i in range(1, 62)]
print(Fs)
df['Fs'] = pd.DataFrame(Fs)

file_name = 'GC_vs_GenCode.xlsx'
file_name = df['Fs'].to_excel(file_name)

df2 = pd.read_excel('/Users/.../Code/GC_vs_GenCode.xlsx')

comp=[]

for F in Fs:
    dif = f"match (n)-[r:GenCode_has_{F}]->(m) return count(r) as count"
    print(dif)
    difrel=runq(dif)
    print(difrel)
    comp.append(difrel.iloc[0,0])
    dataf['GenCode_has_F']=pd.DataFrame(comp)
   

file_name = 'GC_vs_GenCode.xlsx'
file_name = dataf['GenCode_has_F'].to_excel(file_name)
```

I thought `.to_excel` will know how to add things up into the next empty column but it does not.